# Spacy error on unnamed vectors when apply simple training model

Tags: python-3.6, spacy

I am testing out with the spacy sample NER code. Which is directly copied from the spacy website https://spacy.io/usage/training. i just add the import spacy and random myself

```
import spacy
import random

TRAIN_DATA = [
     ("Uber blew through $1 million a week", {'entities': [(0, 4, 'ORG')]}),
     ("Google rebrands its business apps", {'entities': [(0, 6, "ORG")]})]

nlp = spacy.blank('en')
optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
for i in range(20):
    random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
    for text, annotations in TRAIN_DATA:
        nlp.update([text], [annotations], sgd=optimizer)
nlp.to_disk('/model')
```

however, when I run the code. It shows the error.

```
Warning: Unnamed vectors -- this won't allow multiple vectors models to be loaded. (Shape: (0, 0))
```

I searched on the community but got no clue. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 7):

Put `nlp.vocab.vectors.name = 'spacy_pretrained_vectors'` before optimizer will be enough

```
import spacy
import random

TRAIN_DATA = [
     ("Uber blew through $1 million a week", {'entities': [(0, 4, 'ORG')]}),
     ("Google rebrands its business apps", {'entities': [(0, 6, "ORG")]})]

nlp = spacy.blank('en')
nlp.vocab.vectors.name = 'spacy_pretrained_vectors'
optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
for i in range(20):
    random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
    for text, annotations in TRAIN_DATA:
        nlp.update([text], [annotations], sgd=optimizer)
nlp.to_disk('/model')
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!